# How to get path chooser dialog box to save file using GWT

Tags: java, file, gwt, filechooser

I'm developing an application in which I want to create an 'MS-EXCEL' file from application by calling a service and I want to return that file as a response to the client machine with a dialog box to save file.

Currently I am hard coding the path in program. I can't use swing I want to implement this in GWT.

```
     if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("DigitalInputReport")) {    
                    response.setHeader(
                                                "Content-disposition",
                                                "attachment; filename=\"DIR_"
                                                        + TimeZoneUtil.getPdfDate(fromDate) + "_"
                                                        + TimeZoneUtil.getPdfDate(toDate) + ".csv\"");

        List<ReportData> datas = new ArrayList<ReportData>();
        // Calling Service
        datas = fleetTrackingServiceImpl.getDIN2SummaryReport(vehicle,
                                    fromDate, toDate);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\DIR_"
                                                + TimeZoneUtil.getPdfDate(fromDate) + "_"
                                                + TimeZoneUtil.getPdfDate(toDate) + ".csv");
                                        try {
                                            hashMapRunDur = datas.get(datas.size() - 1).getRunHashMap();
                                            hashMapStopDur = datas.get(datas.size() - 1)
                                                    .getStopHashMap();
                                            int runDur = 0, stopDur = 0;
                                            writer.append("From Hour");
                                            writer.append(',');
                                            writer.append("To Hour");
                                            writer.append(',');
                                            writer.append("Minutes ON");
                                            writer.append(',');
                                            writer.append("Minutes OFF");
                                            writer.append(',');
                                            writer.append('\n');
                                            writer.append("Date");
                                            writer.append(',');
                                            String dtChk = null, dtChkPrev = null;
                                            for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++) {

                                                if (i == 0) {
                                                    dtChk = datas.get(i).getToDate();
                                                    writer.append(datas.get(i).getToDate());
                                                    writer.append(',');
                                                    writer.append('\n');
                                                    writer.append(datas.get(i).getRunTime());
                                                    writer.append(',');
                                                    writer.append(datas.get(i).getStopTime());
                                                    writer.append(',');
                                                    writer.append(datas.get(i).getRunDur());
                                                    writer.append(',');
                                                    writer.append(datas.get(i).getStopDur());
                                                    writer.append('\n');
                                                } else {
                                                    dtChkPrev = dtChk;
                                                    dtChk = datas.get(i).getToDate();
                                                    if (dtChkPrev.equals(dtChk)) {
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getRunTime());
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getStopTime());
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getRunDur());
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getStopDur());
                                                        writer.append('\n');
                                                    } else {
                                                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : hashMapRunDur
                                                                .entrySet()) {
                                                            runDur = (Integer.valueOf(e.getValue()));
                                                            stopDur = (Integer.valueOf(hashMapStopDur
                                                                    .get(e.getKey())));
                                                            break;
                                                        }
// To delete first entry
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterRun = hashMapRunDur
                                                                .entrySet().iterator();
                                                        while (iterRun.hasNext()) {
                                                            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterRun
                                                                    .next();
                                                            if (datas.get(i - 1).getToDate()
                                                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())) {
                                                                iterRun.remove();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterStop = hashMapStopDur
                                                                .entrySet().iterator();
                                                        while (iterStop.hasNext()) {
                                                            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterStop
                                                                    .next();
                                                            if (datas.get(i - 1).getToDate()
                                                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())) {
                                                                iterStop.remove();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        writer.append(' ');
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append("Total ON/OFF");
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(formatIntoHHMMSSWithOutDay(runDur));
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(formatIntoHHMMSSWithOutDay(stopDur));
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append('\n');

                                                        dtChk = datas.get(i).getToDate();
                                                        writer.append("Date");
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getToDate());
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append('\n');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getRunTime());
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getStopTime());
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getRunDur());
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(datas.get(i).getStopDur());
                                                        writer.append('\n');
                                                    }
                                                    if (i == datas.size() - 1) {
                                                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : hashMapRunDur
                                                                .entrySet()) {
                                                            runDur = (Integer.valueOf(e.getValue()));
                                                            stopDur = (Integer.valueOf(hashMapStopDur
                                                                    .get(e.getKey())));
                                                            break;
                                                        }
                                                        writer.append(' ');
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append("Total ON/OFF");
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(formatIntoHHMMSSWithOutDay(runDur));
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append(formatIntoHHMMSSWithOutDay(stopDur));
                                                        writer.append(',');
                                                        writer.append('\n');
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            }
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } finally {
                                            writer.flush();
                                            writer.close();
                                        }
                }
```

**This is Servlet coding. When I invoke it am getting output here(c://windows/temp/DIR_...) with full content but not in file which i download at client side(I get only 'DigitalInputReport'). Kindly explain me briefly...**

```
csvBtn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {
                String gwt = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL();
                Window.open(
                        gwt
                                + "generateCSVServlet?name=DigitalInputReport&fromDate="
                                + fromDate + "&toDate=" + toDate + "&compName="
                                + LoginDashboardModule.companyId
                                + "&brnchName=" + LoginDashboardModule.branchId
                                + "&userName=" + LoginDashboardModule.userName
                                + "&selectedVehicle=" + selectedVehicle, null, null);               
            }
        });
```

**This is Client-Side Code**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File temp = new File("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\DIR_"
                                        + TimeZoneUtil.getPdfDate(fromDate) + "_"
                                        + TimeZoneUtil.getPdfDate(toDate) + ".csv");

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(temp)))
                                {
                                    String isCurrentLine;
                                    while ((isCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                        response.getOutputStream().write("\n".getBytes());
                                        byte[] b = isCurrentLine.getBytes();
                                        response.getOutputStream().write(b);
                                    }

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

**Using this code I can directly return contents of file to client-side from server-side and save file on client machine with his wish.**

Answer (score 1):

Use FileUpload to get the path.

```
A widget that wraps the HTML <input type='file'> element.
```

And in changeEvent you can get filename/path:

```
FileUpload file = (FileUpload) event.getSource();
String filename = file.getFilename();
```

Comment: Actually I am creating Excel Sheet from Server-side and I dont have any event in server-side code. 

Button is in client side coding.

Comment: I don't understand if your want to save your file on server or client side. If client side, you can get a filename from client, then save the excel file using the filename. However, the path to save is controlled by user's browser. You can't write a file directly to client absolute path.

Comment: @criszhao I would say he wants save file created on server to other place on server, but want user to choose where on server to save it. Ibadur you should probably edit your question to clear this server/client thing